# Baby Rudin Ex 3.14 (a) proof -verification

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Ex 3.14 (a): If $\{s_{n}\}$ is a complex sequence, define its arithmetic mean $\sigma_{n}$ by $$\sigma_{n} = \dfrac{s_{0}+s_{1}+ \dots +s_{n}}{n+1}$$ $(n=,1,2, \dots)$

if $\lim s_{n} = s$ prove that $\lim \sigma_{n} = s$.

Attempt:

Given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N>0$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $|s_{n} - s| < \epsilon$. There also exists another positive integer $N'$ such that $n\geq N'$ implies $|\frac{s_{0}+s_{1}+ \dots + s_{N-1} -Ns}{n+1}| < \epsilon$. For $n \geq \max\{N, N'\}$

\begin{align}
|\sigma_{n}-s| & \leq |\frac{s_{0}+s_{1}+\dots+s_{N-1}-Ns}{n+1}| + |\frac{(s_{N}-s)+(s_{N+1}-s)+\dots+(s_{n}-s)}{n+1}| \\
& \leq \epsilon + \frac{1}{n+1}(|s_{N+1}-s| + |s_{N+2}-s| + \dots +|s_{n}-s|) \\
& < \epsilon + \frac{n-N+1}{n+1}\epsilon\\
\end{align}

I'm nearly done but am not sure what I can make this final quantity less than...

Comment: this has been answered many times here. search cesaro means

Comment: Your proof is correct, which is a case of 'Cauchy's limit', 'Stolz formula' or 'Cesaro sums'. The final quantity is less than $10000 \varepsilon$ provided n large

Comment: Thanks @RichardChen